# Submitting iOS App Using Monaca

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, monaca

Documentation on the Monaca site for submitting an iOS app to App Store is not consistent with what I'm seeing on iTunes Connect. I have an individual account, so I don't have the option to submit as an Agent per the documentation. I'm thinking that explains why all subsequent steps in the Monaca documentation is different from what I'm seeing on iTunes Connect. I don't see an Upload Binary option for the binary build I downloaded from Monaca. The only option I see is to submit using Xcode or Application Loader. Any help pointing me to the proper way to submit is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The only way is to indeed use Application Loader or Xcode. I use Application Loader, personally. This means you must be using a Mac.

Comment: You can also use macincloud.com to rent a mac for a US dollar per hour, that you can RDP into.

Comment: Monaca also have an option whereby they will upload the app on your behalf, but this does mean giving them your Apple credentials, see: https://monaca.io/pricing-detail.html, line item: iOS App upload